# jquery $(window).height() not implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, height

When running the jquery below on document ready, I get a not implemented error on the assignment of top. If that line is removed, the assignment of left works just fine. I'm developing in an IE7 environment. Is this a browser implementation issue?

```
top = $(window).height();
left = $(window).width();
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual error you're getting? And perhaps how/where you're using this code in your page?

Comment: what version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: According to the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/height/ the code you posted should work. My guess is your error lies somewhere else.

Comment: It works on mine. If you think it is a bug, [report it](http://bugs.jquery.com/).

Comment: When are you calling the code? It needs more context than the 2 lines you have given.

Comment: @hamczu I'm using JQuery 1.7.1 minified.

Comment: @jonathansampson The actual error is a popup that says "Not Implemented" and when I choose to debug, points to that line. If that line is removed, the code runs fine.

Comment: @epascarello I'm running it in the $(document).ready(function(){}) portion of the page. I mentioned that, but I didn't include it in code form.

Comment: are top and left already declared variables? if not you will need to add var to the beginning of each of those lines.

Comment: @derek Are you using IE7 and JQuery 1.7.1?

Comment: @travmckinney Genius. I don't know why left worked and top didn't, but that was the issue. I've never used var declaration in javascript, assuming it just dynamically allocated as needed. Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, it has nothing to do with the jQuery code. window.[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) means something in JavaScript and since you do not delcare var, you are trying to override it! So you should Always scope your variables and if it needs to be global, change your variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That explains why it worked with left but not with top. +1 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Put `var` before the variables.

Because `top` is `==` top `window`.

Credit goes to [`@travmckinney`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146695/jquery-window-height-not-implemented/10146890#comment13011333_10146695)